# AWS Quicksight calculated field vs Custom SQL query

Tags: business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

As with any other BI tool AWS Quicksight allows you to add calculated fields. So far, I haven't run into any limitations using them, but I can't help but wonder what is the better design approach? Adding a calculated field in my custom SQL query or using the calculated fields feature?

Comment: Have you learned anything in your Quicksight experience since you asked this to provide any insight to new users? I was curious about this question as well.

Comment: @barnesm999 I have posted my response below. Hope it is helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there is a few ways to work with calculated fields in Quicksight:

1. You do them in your SQL query
2. You add them to your dataset
3. You add them to your analysis

I am not sure if this would be considered best practice, but my preference has evolved to:

1. Use calculated fields on an analysis, if I want to contain that field to the analysis only.
2. If the field will be used more than once, I add them to the dataset. This is my go-to method if I am not using a direct query and relying on the default UI.
3. For any complicated calculations that are not supported by Quicksight calculated fields or if I am already using a direct query, I'll do everything in SQL.

The downside of calculated fields is that looking up their computation can be a little annoying as it involves a few clicks. Also, I find it hard to differentiate between which fields are calculated and which aren't so I have a habit of prefixing calculated fields with `_`, e.g. `_date` or `_day_of_week` if it is a calculated field.